# Sci fi story where a woman demonstrating a knife with a safety feature cuts herself when the safety is turned off

Tags: story-identification

Please help to identify a sci fi story, English speaking author, old classics (50s or 60s).

The last scene of a story is where a woman is desperate to sell an energy field safe knife that does not cut flesh, but something goes wrong and the protective field is switched off. A woman trying to demonstrate that the knife is safe cuts through her hand . Roughly remember last words

> '*blade went through her hand as if through soft butter'.*

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Where I live we call this kind of safety for a knife a "sheath" ;).

Comment: thank you so much for everyone who answered! This is it exactly!! I can't thank you enough!!! I read this story when I was a child as a translation to Russian before I have learned English and by now I am vaguely remembering the plot. Its been bugging me for years that I couldn't find the story! 
And no I can read it in it's original language. 
Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 30):

While some of the details don’t match, I think that’s probably [“The Little Black Bag”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Black_Bag) by C M Kornbluth. The woman is trying to use the scalpel (and some other advanced medical instruments) rather than to sell it, and it’s her throat that she cuts rather than her hand.

> Smiling, the knife plunging in and its microtomesharp metal shearing through major and minor blood vessels and muscular tissue and pharynx, Angie cut her throat.

Comment: Beat me to it, but I'm confident you are correct -- that was my instant thought, despite the differences in the description :)  Here -- the final lines: " Angie smiled with serene confidence a smile that was to shock hardened morgue attendants. She set the Cutaneous Series knife to three centimeters before drawing it across her neck. Smiling, knowing the blade would cut only the dead horny tissue of the epidermis and the live tissue of the dermis, mysteriously push aside all major and minor blood vessels and muscular tissue—"

Comment: "Smiling, the knife plunging in and its microtomesharp metal shearing through major and minor blood vessels and muscular tissue and pharynx, Angie cut her throat. In the few minutes it took the police, summoned by the shrieking Mrs. Coleman, to arrive, the instruments had become crusted with rust, and the flasks which had held vascular glue and clumps of pink, rubbery alveoli and spare grey cells and coils of receptor nerves held only black slime, and from them when opened gushed the foul gases of decomposition. "

Comment: @K-H-W - you can edit those lines directly into the answer...

Comment: If so, that would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132648/name-of-a-story-about-a-doctors-bag-of-surgical-instruments-transported-back-in/132649#132649

Comment: Couldn't think of the title but this story immediately came to mind for me, also.